# Sql query using subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm currently doing a sql problem.

Q: For each maker find the number of PC ,Laptop and Printer as countOFPC,countOfLaptop,countOfPrinter they have produced.

The database scheme consists of four tables: Product(maker, model, type)

The table "Product" includes information about the maker, model number, and type ('PC', 'Laptop', or 'Printer'). It is assumed that model numbers in the Product table are unique for all the makers and product types.

Here is what I have tried, but it  doesn't work correctly.

```
  select distinct  maker, 
            (select count(* )               
            from Product p
           where p.maker=maker and p.type='Laptop')countOfLaptop,

                         (select count(*)     
                         from Product p
                         where p.maker=maker and p.type='PC') countOfPc,
                                                        (select count(*)     
                                                         from Product p
                                                         where p.maker=maker and p.type='Printer') countOFPrinter
```

from Product

What is wrong, and how can I correct it?

Comment: You you are not reading  from maker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand what @Pharm X. Bach has said. You've said that you need this information for each "maker"

You can also use CTE (Common Table Expression)

```
WITH ProductFlags AS (
  SELECT MODEL,
         TYPE,
         MAKER,
         (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flgPrdTypePC,
         (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Laptop' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flgPrdTypeLaptop,
         (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Printer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flgPrdTypePrinter
   FROM PRODUCT
)
  SELECT SUM(flgPrdTypePC) AS countOfTypePC,
         SUM(flgPrdTypeLaptop) AS countOfTypeLaptop,
         SUM(flgPrdTypePrinter) AS countOfTypePrinter,
         MAKER
    FROM ProductFlags
GROUP BY MAKER;
```

Or without CTE based on flags with subquery

```
SELECT SUM(flgPrdTypePC) AS countOfTypePC,
       SUM(flgPrdTypeLaptop) AS countOfTypeLaptop,
       SUM(flgPrdTypePrinter) AS countOfTypePrinter,
       MAKER
  FROM (SELECT MODEL,
               TYPE,
               MAKER,
               (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flgPrdTypePC,
               (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Laptop' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flgPrdTypeLaptop,
               (CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Printer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS flgPrdTypePrinter
          FROM PRODUCT)
GROUP BY MAKER;
```

P.S. I would recommend to also think about using **UPPER** when comparing **TYPE** column with value ex. `UPPER(TYPE) = 'PC' or UPPER(TYPE) = UPPER('PC')`
If you are 100% sure of your data than go ahead with above proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should change to this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countOfPc, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Laptop' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countOfLaptop, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Printer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countOfPrinter 
FROM 
    product;
```

In case you only count for unique `model number`, you could use this instead:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countOfPc, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Laptop' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countOfLaptop, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Printer' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) countOfPrinter 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        model, type 
    FROM 
        product
);
```